# MySQL Error 1060: Duplicate column name ALTER TABLE

Tags: php, alter-table, mysql-error-1060

I am having some problems with a query because of errors in the code that I did not create.

```
$query = $this->db->query("ALTER TABLE `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer` ADD `customer_type` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL;
```

I'm not a coder, but have so far fixed (I think) the error. By comparing with other queries that don't throw errors and reading quite a few similar posts on stackoverflow, I added a missing quote, a parenthese, and semi-colon. No more error, but not sure if this is even the correct way of doing it? I ended up with this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("ALTER TABLE `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer` ADD `customer_type` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL;");
```

But now, I get a duplicate column error 1060 "duplicate column name". So I did the same thing, googled the heck out of it, search stackoverflow and found some examples using aliases and a bunch of extra lines of code which is way above my head. This code lives in side a .php file, would someone kindly hold my hand through this? You could consider it your good deed for the day! Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sounds like this is just a utility script that's already been run. This kind of query only needs to be run once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the column already exists in your table, most likely the former programmer wanted to add the column and forgot to delete the query aftewrads.

Comment: Of course it does, thanks for pointing me in the obvious direction. Also dtbarne!